# 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: exampleDb.test.$ == null -- in Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing records in a loop into the MongoDB from Node.

Node code

```
for (i=1;i<10;i++) { fninsertDocument('title'+i) }

function fninsertDocument (data){
        collection.insert({title:data}, {w: 1}, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            assert.equal(1, result.length)
        });
}
```

after writing the first record it is throwing error.
"11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: exampleDb.test.$ == null"

I have created index on title field in mongo shell. but still same problem. have read other stack answers but no use. please help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

Before inserting the data, I did stringify and parsed the data again. That's it, problem solved!
But don't know exactly what was exact reason!

```
function fninsertDocument (data){
    try {

        console.log(data.id+data.Title) //delete

        **var tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))**

        collection.insert(tmp, {w: 1}, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            assert.equal(1, result.length)
//            console.log(result);

        });
    }
```